# Coffeescript namespacing with different files

Tags: class, coffeescript, namespaces

Consider the following classes:

```
class A
  constructor: ->
    @nestedA = new NestedA()

  class NestedA
    constructor: ->

  @NestedA = NestedA

@A = A

class B
  constructor: ->
    @nestedB = new NestedB()

  class NestedB
    constructor: ->

  @NestedB = NestedB

@B = B
```

In this way, classes `A` and `B` are available in the global namespace, and `NestedA` and `NestedB` are only available through the `A` and `B` namespaces, respectively. I like this approach, **but** this can lead to the separate coffeescript files getting rather large. Thus I was wondering whether there was a way to separate the classes (NestedA and NestedB) into separate coffeescript files *and still maintain the namespaces*?

Answer (score 0):

You could use RequireJS to load NestedA.coffee as a dependency into A.coffee (and do the same for the Bs).  And then use RequireJS to load A.coffee into your main application in the same way.

```
Class A
  @NestedA = require('cs!NestedA)
```

This should work but it might be a bit of an architectural shift if you are not already using RequireJS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've considered it - I just really wanted to use vanilla cofffeescript, and was hoping the language supported something like this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way. This approach is very similar to what TypeScript does, but the pattern fits just as well in CoffeeScript.

```
#a.coffee
A = do (A = A ? {})->

    class Foo
        constructor: ->
            @nestedFoo = new NestedFoo()

    class NestedFoo
        constructor ->
        greet: ->
            console.log('Hello World')

    #exports
    A.Foo = Foo
    A.NestedFoo = NestedFoo
    A

#somwhere-else.coffee

foo = new A.Foo()
foo.nestedFoo.greet() #yields 'Hello World'
```

This approach has the advantage that you can add as many other features to the namespace from whatever other files you want.